# Why do I get a Table.CacheUpdateException whenever I add an item to the Table Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

Hi everyone why if I add an item in a hardcoded way to a Vaadin Table with ColumnGenerators I always get a Table.CacheUpdateException?

Here is the code:

```
// Generated Table columns
        Table tableWithGeneratedCol = new Table();

        tableWithGeneratedCol.addContainerProperty(
                "date",     Date.class,   null, "Date",         null, null);
        tableWithGeneratedCol.addContainerProperty(
                "quantity", Double.class, null, "Quantity (l)", null, null);
        tableWithGeneratedCol.addContainerProperty(
                "price",    Double.class, null, "Price (e/l)",  null, null);
        tableWithGeneratedCol.addContainerProperty(
                "total",    Double.class, null, "Total (e)",    null, null);


        tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(), // date column
                                                     new Double(10),                    // quantity column
                                                     new Double(10),                    // price column
                                                     new Double(0)                  // total column
                                                    }, 1); // itemId
        tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                     new Double(16.2),                  // quantity column
                                                     new Double(21.2),                  // price column
                                                     new Double(0)                      // total column
                                                    }, 2); // itemId
        tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                     new Double(10),                    // quantity column
                                                     new Double(22),                    // price column
                                                     new Double(0)                  // total column                                         
                                                    }, 3); // itemId
        tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                     new Double(10),                    // quantity column
                                                     new Double(20),                    // price column
                                                     new Double(0)                  // total column
                                                    }, 4); // itemId
        tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                     new Double(15),                    // quantity column
                                                     new Double(19.12),                 // price column
                                                     new Double(0)                                          
                                                    }, 5); // itemId
        tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                     new Double(10),                    // quantity column
                                                     new Double(20.30),                 // price column
                                                     new Double(0)                  // total column     
                                                    }, 6); // itemId
        tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                     new Double(50),                    // quantity column
                                                     new Double(32.89),                 // price column
                                                     new Double(0)                  // total column
                                                    }, 7); // itemId
```

Then, if I add another row:

```
tableWithGeneratedCol.addItem(new Object[] { new GregorianCalendar().getTime(),
                                                     new Double(50),                    // quantity column
                                                     new Double(32.89),                 // price column
                                                     new Double(0)                  // total column
                                                    }, 8); // itemId
```

I get:

```
SEVERE: 
com.vaadin.ui.Table$CacheUpdateException: Error during Table cache update. Additional causes not shown.
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.maybeThrowCacheUpdateExceptions(Table.java:1739)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1728)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.attach(Table.java:4244)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.setParent(AbstractComponent.java:484)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.addComponent(AbstractComponentContainer.java:210)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractOrderedLayout.addComponent(AbstractOrderedLayout.java:90)
    at com.example.table_chapter_5_21.TableUI.init(TableUI.java:357)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:645)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:222)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1406)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
    at com.example.table_chapter_5_21.DateColumnGenerator.generateCell(DateColumnGenerator.java:27)
    at com.example.table_chapter_5_21.DateColumnGenerator.generateCell(DateColumnGenerator.java:1)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.parseItemIdToCells(Table.java:2334)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.getVisibleCellsNoCache(Table.java:2195)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1717)
    ... 34 more

Dec 19, 2014 10:24:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.example.table_chapter_5_21.TableUI$Servlet] in context with path [/Table_Chapter_5.21] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: com.vaadin.ui.Table$CacheUpdateException: Error during Table cache update. Additional causes not shown.] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
    at com.example.table_chapter_5_21.DateColumnGenerator.generateCell(DateColumnGenerator.java:27)
    at com.example.table_chapter_5_21.DateColumnGenerator.generateCell(DateColumnGenerator.java:1)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.parseItemIdToCells(Table.java:2334)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.getVisibleCellsNoCache(Table.java:2195)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1717)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.attach(Table.java:4244)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.setParent(AbstractComponent.java:484)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.addComponent(AbstractComponentContainer.java:210)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractOrderedLayout.addComponent(AbstractOrderedLayout.java:90)
    at com.example.table_chapter_5_21.TableUI.init(TableUI.java:357)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:645)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:222)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1406)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Then if I wait for a while and then reload the page, everything starts working again...

Why this exception? And why with ColumnGenerators?

Comment: Works for me on Vaadin 7.3.6, WildFly 8 and Java 7. Since Vaadin code base is open and you have stacktrace you can debug Table

Comment: Don't you think that the NullPointerException is the cause?
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @AndréSchild I thought of that too, but if I wait a little bit and then reload the page, all starts working again, if the problem would be a NullPointerException of my code (not Vaadin's) I guess that I should not be able to render the page, but as I said, if I wait for a while and then reload, the exception disappears and I can view the page with the table. It is really strange though.

Comment: @kukis Could you please post the code you used? Did you use columnGenerators?

Comment: From the Book of Vaadin I have found this phrase: `"The generator is called for all the visible (or more accurately cached) items in a table.`" *Chapter 5.21.5 Generated Columns*. They only make a hint without actually describing what do they mean with *more accurately cached*...

Comment: @user3019104 sure, http://pastebin.com/b6cd3DrE

Comment: @kukis Thanks, the code you linked me is the same of mine, anyway, I do not know why, but now it seems to work for me too. :)

Comment: http://imgace.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/the-essence-of-programming.png :)